# Converting Gulp 3 file to Gulp 4

Tags: webpack, gulp

I have this `gulpfile.js` which I'm trying to convert to Gulp 4 and Webpack 4. I basically just yarn upgraded everything to the latest and set about addressing each error.

I've got it to compile and serve, but it doesn't watch and sync correctly.

I think it's compiling twice because of janky function nesting and I get this error on scss changes:

`ConcurrentCompilationError in plugin "webpack-stream"`

I've looked at a bunch of Gulp 4 boilerplates and I've tried my best to interpret with my limited js skills. I'm not a total noobie, but I'm not a js ninja either.

Here's the current Frankenstein version... any help getting it streamlined and happy in Gulp 4 / Webpack 4 would be greatly appreciated:

```
const browserSync = require('browser-sync').create();
const gulp = require('gulp');
const php = require('gulp-connect-php');
const project = require('./package.json').project;
const webpack = require('webpack');
const webpackConfig = require('./webpack.config.js');
const webpackStream = require('webpack-stream');

const compile = () => {
  return gulp.src(`${project.js}/index.js`, { allowEmpty: true })
    .pipe(
      webpackStream(webpackConfig, webpack)
        .on('error', (err) => {
          console.log('WEBPACK ERROR', err);
        })
    )
    .pipe(gulp.dest('../web'))
    .pipe(browserSync.stream({
      match: '**/*.css',
    }));
};
const watchMarkup = () => {
  gulp.watch(['**/*.html'], () => {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
};
const watchScript = () => {
  gulp.watch([
    `${project.src.js}/**/*.js`,
    `${project.src.js}/**/*.jsx`,
  ], () => {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
};
const watchStyle = () => {
  gulp.watch(`${project.src.scss}/**/*.scss`, () => {
    browserSync.reload();
  });
};

const sync = () => {
  browserSync.init({
    proxy: '127.0.0.1:8010',
    ghostMode: false,
    host: 'localhost',
    open: true,
    notify: false,
    port: 8000,
  });
};

const connectPHP = () => {
  php.server({ base: '../web/', port: 8010, keepalive: true });
};

const watch = gulp.parallel(watchMarkup, watchScript, watchStyle);
const serve = gulp.series(compile, gulp.parallel(connectPHP, sync), watch);

gulp.task('start', gulp.series(compile, serve));

gulp.task('default', gulp.series['compile']);
```

Comment: I would modify most of your tasks like so const watchStyle = (done) => {… and then call done();  right before the last closing brace of the task, so done(); };   See if that helps - I doubt it deals with your compilation error though.  But you will ultimately have to make the changes I suggest.

Comment: Also use gulp.task('default', gulp.series('compile));  Not an array.